# Jquery .Select() in mobile browser will auto clear all input text

Tags: javascript, jquery, input

I have create some input text and when I click the input text,it will auto select the input text. It is workable in desktop browser, however when I open it in the mobile browser such as `Google Chrome`, it will auto select input text and clear all the text in the input.

```
$("input[type='text']").click(function () {
    $(this).focus();
    $(this).select();
    $(this).setSelectionRange(0, 999999999);

});
```

May I know is it have any solution for this condition, Thank You!!!

Answer (score 0):

Finally, I have solve it, I have to specified which element id of my input text,and it workable for all device's browser.

```
$("#input1").click(function () {
    document.getElementById("input1").select();
});
```